# is there a way to know what thread is causing the stack overflow

Tags: multithreading, macos, xamarin.mac

im in troubles with some stack overflows, im not sure where the stacks happen, i am developing an app with xamarin mac, i used instruments tools from xcode for checking the allocations and the leaks and i got this in the App's output.

failed to suspend thread 0xb06a3000, hopefully it is dead

failed to suspend thread 0xb0725000, hopefully it is dead

failed to suspend thread 0xb0093000, hopefully it is dead

failed to suspend thread 0xb11af000, hopefully it is dead

Thread finished:  #16;

failed to suspend thread 0xb0115000, hopefully it is dead

Thread started:  #17;

Thread started:  #18;

Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x210ad5, fault addr: 0xb01954d8

failed to suspend thread 0xb06a3000, hopefully it is dead

failed to suspend thread 0xb0195000, hopefully it is dead

failed to suspend thread 0xb0093000, hopefully it is dead

Stacktrace

at  <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.int_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr)

at MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.RunModalForWindow (MonoMac.AppKit.NSWindow) [0x00034] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/xamcore-lion-master-3.2/c508e5a1/source/xamcore/src/preprocessed-build/32-bit/monomac/src/AppKit/NSApplication.g.cs:457

at SoundHound.SyncGUIController.ShowSync () [0x00064] in /Users/Norman/Projects/Aquilesss/Trackhunter/Trackhunter/Controllers/SyncGUIController.cs:72

at SoundHound.MainGUIController.ReceiveToolStripMenuItemClick () [0x00037] in /Users/Norman/Projects/Aquilesss/Trackhunter/Trackhunter/Controllers/MainGUIController.cs:2570
  at SoundHound.AppDelegate.ReceiveToolStripMenuItemClick (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject) [0x00007] in /Users/Norman/Projects/Aquilesss/Trackhunter/Trackhunter/AppDelegate.cs:265

at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.[SoundHound.AppDelegate.Void ReceiveToolStripMenuItemClick(MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject)] (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject,MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector,MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject)

at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.[SoundHound.AppDelegate.Void ReceiveToolStripMenuItemClick(MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject)] (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject,MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector,MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject)

at  <0xffffffff>

at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.NSApplicationMain (int,string[])

at MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.Main (string[]) [0x00041] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/xamcore-lion-master-3.2/c508e5a1/source/xamcore/src/preprocessed-build/32-bit/monomac/src/AppKit/NSApplication.cs:98

at SoundHound.MainClass.Main (string[]) [0x0007f] in /Users/Norman/Projects/Aquilesss/Trackhunter/Trackhunter/Main.cs:53

at (wrapper runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)

Native stacktrace:

Debug info from gdb:

^D

^D

quit

^D

........

and this continues several times, im not what to do someone has any ideas???

Comment: I've begun to notice these *"failed to suspend thread"* messages on my application output as well, did you happen to get anywhere with this?